# iOS 7: Keyboard not showing after leaving modal ViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, keyboard, segue, modalviewcontroller

I've got a `HomeViewController` that has different modal segues to several other `UIViewControllers`. If I try to show the keyboard on a `UITextField` within the HomeView, everything works fine. However, if I try to show the keyboard on a `UITextField` (using `becomeFirstResponder`) after returning from any of the modal View Controllers, the keyboard never shows.

Here's some sample code from one of the setups I've tried:

In `HomeViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    static BOOL firstTimeComplete = false;
    if (!firstTimeComplete) {
        firstTimeComplete = true;
    } else {
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview:textField];
        [textField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:3]
    }
}
```

In `ModalViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender 
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Where `done:` is linked to the "Done" button via a touch up inside event.

A few things I've tried:

- Converting the modal segues to push segues fixes the issue, but I don't want a Nav bar in any of the child views
- I've tried disabling and enabling animations when dismissing the
  modal view controller (using `dismissViewControllerAnimated:`)
- Using unwind segues in the storyboard rather than doing it programmatically

Anyone have an idea of what may be going on?

Comment: Without looking at the source code, it is quite hard to come up with any suggestion.

Comment: Added some code, let me know if any other part of the code might be relevant

Comment: I'm using the exact same code, and when I run that in an application, present the modal, and dismiss it, after 3 seconds the keyboard comes up. https://www.dropbox.com/s/iimz6c7ooq68lxr/Screenshot%202014-08-21%2016.07.14.png

Comment: 1) You did not call [super viewDidAppear:animated]
2) In place like that i have next workaround:

Comment: Thanks for the info Mike! That's probably what I should try as well. I'm helping someone out on an existing project, so I'll try chopping out code till I find out what specific line is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deleting tons of code, I finally found out that a custom NavigationController was being used and this was the root cause:

```
@implementation MSLNavigationController

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

The app doesn't need this code, so I've nuked the file. (But an explanation as to why this would be hiding the keyboard would be awesome :))

Answer (score 1):

1. You did not call `[super viewDidAppear:animated]`
2. In place like that i have workaround that works pretty well

   ```
   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];

       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
       {
           if (self.textView.text.isNotEmpty)
           {
               [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this problem for some time, so I'll post here what I found out.

I was calling `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` in `viewWillAppear` but on iOS 7, after the modal was dismissed, the keyboard would not show again, even when you would tap on the textField.

For me calling `textField.resignFirstResponder()` when the modal is presented, solved the issue. It seems like the input field was already marked as first responder and then would not react to the new calls.