# iOS 7: Keyboard not showing when using Modal segue & autorotate == NO

Tags: ios, ios7, keyboard, segue, autorotate

(This an extension of [iOS 7: Keyboard not showing after leaving modal ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434095/ios-7-keyboard-not-showing-after-leaving-modal-viewcontroller/25435436#25435436))

I've got a `HomeViewController` that uses a `NavigationController`. Clicking a button takes you to `ModalViewController` using a modal segue. Pressing the back button then takes you back to the `HomeViewController`, which then pops up a keyboard. The weird part though is that the keyboard never shows up. I've verified that the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` does get fired , `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` doesn't and `[textfield isFirstResponder]` returns true. Which means the keyboard should be shown right??

I've verified that this only occurs if I have a modal segue, and the `NavigationController::shouldAutorotate` returns `NO`.

I've copied the relevant code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

**NavigationController.m:**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

**HomeViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (firstTimeComplete) {
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview:textField];
        [textField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
    }
}
```

**ModalViewController.m:**

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! The problem was because I was using `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` instead of `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`. I think masks are the expected type for `supportedInterfaceOrientations`